# Where can I find the specification for the Class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() method?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, authorization, jls

Regardless of whether I use the Oracle JDK, IBM JDK or the Open JDK (all version 8), I'm noticing that the following method is always returning `null` when the class in question is a JDK library class:

```
    Class clazz = Integer.class;
    CodeSource codeSource = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
```

What I would like to know is whether or not the fact that this is null for a set of classes (namely, the classes supplied by the JDK) is specified somewhere (as opposed to it being a commonly-agreed upon value for these classes, decided by the various implementers).

However, I can't seem to find where this would be specified. I've already checked the following sources and have not found any mention there:

- The Java SE 8 JLS
- The Java SE 8 JVM Spec
- JSR-115 (JavaTM Authorization Contract for Containers 1.5)

Where is this behaviour specified? Or is it indeed not specified and a "happy coincidence" that all three JVM implementations have the same behaviour?

(Bonus points if you can explain how this is implicitly specified as a result of other specifications, which I suspect to be the case!)

Answer (score 1):

Protection domain is an entity which reflects that given class was loaded from specific source with specific permissions and keychains, so in fact every protection domain is always associated with classloader which loaded given class.

Bootstrap (system) classloader hasn't any domains because its classes weren't loaded from 3rd party source (they belong to system itself), so default domain with all permissions is used, which has no CodeSource (because system classes have no specific codebase location or signers, so such thing makes no sense) and has all permissions.

Answering your original question, Java Security isn't a part of Java Language Specification (maybe for historical reasons, maybe to avoid JLS overloading with details). 
Security spec itself is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-specTOC.fm.html), with all security classes behaviour explanation.

Most comprehensive security-related API  description could be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/).

Comment: Voting up because it explains the behavior -- however, *not* marking as the answer because it does *not* answer the question ("Where can I find the specification for the Class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() method?")

Comment: It looks like it's unfortunately not specified anywhere.. :/

Comment: @Marco http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc4.html#a21491 only there. The idea is that spec doesn't cover every possible method, but concepts. So part of domain, which responsible for source which were loaded by classloader is CodeSource: url+keychains. CodeSource can be null, when both are absent, thats exactly what happens for system classes

Comment: So, where does it say that the CodeSource for the Bootstrap classloader should be null? When I say "It's not specified anywhere", that means that "The CodeSource should be null for the Bootstrap classloader" isn't anywhere -- which means that some JVM implementations *can* provide a CodeSource for their classes, theoretically.

Comment: Yes, you are right, theoretically it's still possible, this exactly method behaviour is not covered by spec